# Does Ryanair lease any aircraft?

Tags: airline-operations

Does Ryanair lease any of its aircraft?

And if they do, could the end of the lease period coincide with the start of the low passenger periods? E.g. during the autumn to spring months when holiday traffic is slow, there may be a need to reduce the fleet size.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Aviation, could you please reformulate your question so we can understand better what you are looking for ?

Comment: @PierreChevallier Seems pretty clear to me. Do Ryanair lease their aircraft? Do they arrange for the lease periods to end at times when there's less traffic?

Comment: It's hard to know what the real financial status of a purchased aircraft is. It is common for larger carriers such as Continental (who I use to work for) to report 'they' were purchasing 20ea B757 when each aircraft was in fact purchased and owned by investment groups on a lease back. Continental projected themselves as the owners of their fleet but in fact had negotiated the deal in bulk for third parties. The airline business is all smoke and mirrors - interesting question though. I am sure for the purposes of the question, if Ryanair says 'they' own something that is good enough.

Answer (score 2):

Ryanair mainly buys their aircraft. Part of their ability to offer cheap flights comes from [buying aircraft in bulk and generally only operating a single type of airframe](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/48811/what-fundamental-differences-separate-low-budget-airlines-from-traditional-airli).

[They generally buy new Boeing aircraft](https://www.irishtimes.com/business/transport-and-tourism/ryanair-buys-five-more-737-800-planes-from-boeing-1.1778712) operating [primaraly the 737 series.](https://www.ryanair.com/us/en/useful-info/about-ryanair/fleet)

> ...had agreed to buy five more Boeing 737-800 aircraft, **taking its order
>   book to 180 *new* Boeing planes** worth over $16 billion.

Planespotters.net has a [nice list of the aircraft in Ryanair's fleet](https://www.planespotters.net/airline/Ryanair), with the [exception of this -700](https://www.planespotters.net/airframe/Boeing/737/EI-SEV-Ryanair/E4aRtyPW) the rest of the aircraft only show registration to Ryanair as an owner under owner history.