# Are there fees for international flights crossing through another country's airspace?

Tags: air-traffic-control

When an aircraft flies over another country are there fees associated with such flight? I am thinking particularly of international airline flights, though this might also apply to flights with the same country of origin and destination that transit another country's airspace.

- Are there fees for flying through another country's airspace in general?
- Are there fees for flying through the airspace associated with an airport in another country?

Comment: This is mentioned as part of the [cost breakdown for a flight](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/654/1696).

Comment: ...but I think an answer to this question could add more specific detail than that related question.

Comment: I don't think that question adequately addresses this question; I don't find it to be a duplicate.

Comment: Related: http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/30125/how-does-a-national-atc-make-money

Answer (score 6):

Most countries have implemented route charges billed to aircrafts overflying their territory and by doing so using their control infrastructure. Those fees are usually computed according the distance flown and aircraft weight, small aircrafts (eg. less than 2,000 kg in Europe) may be exempt. They are collected for every flight over the territory, both domestic and international.

In the same way, some countries charge terminal fees when the airport control infrastructure is used.

Those fees are most usually levied for flight performed according IFR (Instrument Flight Rules), not VFR (Visual Flight Rules).

In Europe, the EUROCONTROL organization is empowered by States to collect route charges and terminal fees.

Comment: For example, I flew right seat on an IFR flight through Niger airspace and we specifically avoided flying through Nigeria's airspace—even though this was out of our way—because that would have incurred user fees at the time. This was a 12+ years ago, so things may have changed since then.

Answer (score 1):

[here](http://www.aisro.ro/)  is an example of the charges one has to pay to fly in Romanian airspace. Navigate to publications , AIP , AIP, open chapter GEN , section "Charges for Aerodromes/Heliports and Air Navigation Services" .

Comment: Including more detail from the link would make this answer more useful, especially if that link becomes inaccessible.

Comment: Unfortunately the romanian aip does not have permanent links. You should navigate to aisro.ro , select Publications / AIP and navigate to Gen 4 to see the charges.

Comment: In that case, that would be especially important to include that information in the answer, as well as the information at the link.