# What are the various fees associated with flying?

Tags: air-traffic-control, airspace, landing-fees

I am aware of airport landing fees, fuel fees etc, but it was brought to my attention that there is airspace charges? And especially in Canada, the fees are horrendous. What are the various types of fees airlines and private planes have to pay in terms of airspace and air traffic control fee around the world, and Canada and the US?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does a national ATC make money?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/30125/how-does-a-national-atc-make-money)

Comment: I don't think it is a duplicate. This question is asking what are the various fees (collected by third parties) that a pilot or operator should be aware of.

Comment: @kevin He is asking specifically about fees related to airspace and air traffic control.

Comment: I also don't think it's a duplicate.  I think it's too broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will answer this for the US as that is the jurisdiction I know best.

There are no airspace or ATC usage fees here in the US. The airspace and its resources are free for any plane of any size that conforms to the [FAA's FAR's](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/faa_regulations/) and is legal to fly in a given airspace.

The [FAA is in the process of adding overflight charges](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/international_aviation/overflight_fees/) for aircraft that fly through our airspace but neither land nor depart from the US.

The only fee (somewhat indirectly related but not a component of the airspace its self) is for planes coming in from abroad who will need to pay [some customs fees to enter the country](https://www.cbp.gov/trade/basic-import-export/uftd-info).

Strictly speaking you may be required to carry IFR charts or VFR charts on board to conduct the flight in question in US airspace. These must be [purchased from an official source](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/productcatalog/vfrcharts/). The FAA maintains them but the Pilot must pay for them. [Until recently the FAA also physically printed them](http://airfactsjournal.com/2016/09/end-faa-charts-know/) and they were purchased directly from them but this is no longer the case.

If you extend the question to include airports the answer will drastically change for the US.

Comment: Overflight charges would count wouldn't they?

Comment: Interesting, I did not know about those, adding to the answer now.

Comment: I didn't either until this question, but it seems that it is quite common for countries to charge those that fly over but do not take off or land in that country. Well, at least Canada and U.S.

Comment: Don't some (larger) airports charge landing fees?

Comment: Almost all do but their question was about ATC and airspace if they include airports I will extend my answer.

Comment: You are not required to have charts on board for VFR operations. For IFR, you can use EFBs and are not required to have any paper charts.

Comment: It is worth noting that aeronautical charts are available digitally and can be printed at home without any direct fees incurred. And by way of correction, there is *no* requirement for charts to be purchased from an official source.

Comment: I do not believe that charts printed at home are legal for navigation. But yo u are correct they are available digitally.

Comment: The FAA has an "Airways and Aviation Trust Fund" which (in essence) provides a large chunk of the FAA's funding. The AATF is itself funded in large part from a surcharge on aviation fuel, so that is a kind of fee charged on aviators who buy fuel in the US.